# python dictionary error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an error with this line. I am working with a dictionary from a file with an import. This is the dictionary:

```
users = [{'id':1010,'name':"Administrator",'type':1},{'id':1011,'name':"Administrator2",'type':1}]
```

And the method with which the work is as follows:

```
def addData(dict, entry):
    new = {}
    x = 0
    for i in dict.keys():
        new[i] = entry(x)
        x += 1
    dict.append(new)
```

Where "dict" would be "users", but the error is that the dictionary does not recognize me as such. Can anyone tell me, I have wrong in the dictionary?

Comment: Your `users` variable is actually a list of dictionaries.

Comment: I actually defined a variable as dict in a pyx file but after importing the generated. " pyd" file, I am getting the following error when getting its keys: AttributeError: 'getset_descriptor' object has no attribute 'keys'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking to do something along these lines:

```
users = [{'id':1010,'name':"Administrator",'type':1},{'id':1011,'name':"Administrator2",'type':1}]

new_dict={}

for di in users:
    new_dict[di['id']]={}
    for k in di.keys():
        if k =='id': continue
        new_dict[di['id']][k]=di[k]
        
print(new_dict)    
# {1010: {'type': 1, 'name': 'Administrator'}, 1011: {'type': 1, 'name': 'Administrator2'}}
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> new_dict[1010] 
{'type': 1, 'name': 'Administrator'}
```

Essentially, this is turning a list of anonymous dicts into a dict of dicts that are keys from the key `'id'`

You can more compactly do this in one line:

```
new_dict={d['id']:{k: d[k] for k in d.keys() - {'id'}} for d in users}
# {1010: {'type': 1, 'name': 'Administrator'}, 1011: {'type': 1, 'name': 'Administrator2'}}
```

Answer (score 13):

That's not a dicionary, it's a list of dictionaries! 
**EDIT:** And to make this a little more answer-ish:

```
users = [{'id':1010,'name':"Administrator",'type':1},{'id':1011,'name':"Administrator2",'type':1}]
newusers = dict()
for ud in users:
    newusers[ud.pop('id')] = ud
print newusers
#{1010: {'type': 1, 'name': 'Administrator'}, 1011: {'type': 1, 'name': 'Administrator2'}}
newusers[1012] = {'name': 'John', 'type': 2}
print newusers
#{1010: {'type': 1, 'name': 'Administrator'}, 1011: {'type': 1, 'name': 'Administrator2'}, 1012: {'type': 2, 'name': 'John'}}
```

Which is essentially the same as dawgs answer, but with a simplified approach on generating the new dictionary

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a comment!

Comment: You're right, but without 50 reputation I can't comment (which I would have done). But it seems to me, that this hint might have helped anyway.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your rep. If you fleshed out some details, I'd upvote

Comment: Done. Although it's actually just an improvement to dawgs answer, so not really worth the upvote i guess.